# Screen glitch: unplugging HDMI 14.04

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nouveau

The issue is that if I unplug the HDMI coming from my external monitor (i have many and it wasn't dependent on the make/model) the screen on my laptop gets essentially cut in half, displaying half of the stuff that was on the screen as well as half of what was on the second monitor.

If I unplug the second monitor very slowly (that is, slow enough to see a large degree of stuttering and glitching on the second screen), then the laptop screen comes back on just fine. But, if i pull the HDMI quickly, then I get this screen glitch.

I have tried Super+P as well as the built in screen settings function on the keyboard, neither work. I have also tried loading the terminal to adjust the settings there, but I cannot see the terminal as it loads on the half of the screen I cannot see. Even when the terminal was loaded and visible, trying to type into it did not work.

I am using nouveau graphics driver and not proprietary nvidia drivers (880M) and I have tried using the proprietary drivers but it did not fix the problem.

Pulling the HDMI out quickly effectively stopped my computer from doing anything at all, the only solution is to do a hard shut down.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use the System settings - Screen Display and turn the external monitor off before unplugging?

Comment: If I do this it works just fine, however, having to worry about forgetting or accidentally pulling it out or getting it yanked out by some unforeseeable force is my main concern here. But yes, turning the monitor off first allows me to safely remove the HDMI.

Comment: :-)  Off course.  It's just to know what's happening.  Next questions: Have you tried a different HDMI cable and have you tried going to TTY1 and then back yo TTY7 (GUI) when you have the problem? **[Ctrl][Alt][F7] to go back to the GUI**, [Ctrl][Alt][F1] to go to TTY1.

Comment: I have tried that and pressing the built in keyboards "display" button which, when i have the monitor plugged in and working, changes which display is on or off. Both work before unplugging the HDMI but not after the screen glitch has already happened. I have tried this on the only 2 HDMI cords I own.
Thanks

Comment: Weird... Which version of the proprietary drivers have you tried?

Comment: i have tried the 346 series, 340 series, and 330? series as well as nouveau and nouveau with bumblebee.
I do not like the proprietary drivers as they have caused many issues for me.
Note: this did not happen with the 340 series drivers but the 340 drivers caused many more crashes than any other- so i would like to avoid using that

Comment: I'm out of ideas... Sorry.  The last advice I can give is to disable the NVidia in BIOS until the next driver comes out and use xorg-edgers to be able to roll back-and-forth between versions...

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and consideration. I will give that a shot and reply if that works.

Comment: It works so it seems to have something to do with Nvidia. It might be some problem with my laptop in particular.
I wonder if other people with HP envy's have had similar issues.

Comment: And an upvote as I don't understand why anyone would downvote this question...  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to be having problems that seem to be persistent even with the Linux drivers, There is only one thing left to do:

Install the [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and disable the NVidia GPU in your BIOS until you see an update for NVidia coming in.  Then re-enable it.

I'm sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...

*I reinstalled all xserver, xorg components and deleted then re-installed nvidia-common AFTER doing the above (as it did not work on its own and I do not know if it had made a difference)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Fabby. My other question (about nouveau not recognizing the graphics card) was just a corrupt installation and so I deleted that question entirely (let me know if I should have left it up).

Comment: You've done the right thing...  ;-)